# Buy app after downloaded with promo code

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have an iOS app, and I gave all my beta testers promo codes to get free copies. Since they didn't pay for the app they are not allowed to write reviews in the App Store. One of  my testers wants to know how he can purchase the app so that he'll be allowed to write a review. Is there any way to buy an app if a user has already downloaded it with a promo code?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to undo a purchase from the end user standpoint, and each user would need to contact apple for a manual adjustment to their account (which might not be something that is even done).

The thing you can control is for that user to set up a second Apple ID to complete a legitimate purchase that qualifies to submit a review. You could also gift the app and be in the clear since that doesn't have the review restrictions that a promotional code redemption does.